# Writing a function that asks a user to input a color and then fills a shape with that color

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My task is to write a function, `drawCircle(radius,fillColor)`, that asks a user for the specific radius of the circle and which color they'd like the circle to be filled.

I have the circle-drawing down, but I'm struggling with getting the circle to fill with the user-defined color. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import turtle

def drawCircle(radius, fillColor):
    x=360/300 #This gives the angle
    r=radius#This is the radius of the circle.
    c=fillColor
    c=str("")
    z=1 #Placeholder for the while loop.
    win=turtle.Screen()
    tom=turtle.Turtle()

    fillColor=tom.color()
    tom.begin_fill()

    while (z<=300):
        tom.forward(r)
        tom.right(x)
        tom.forward(r)
        z=z+1
win.exitonclick()
tom.end_fill()
```

This is my function call: `drawCircle(1,"red")`

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You call win.exitonclick before tom.end_fill, so programm exits before filling (as it happens on end_fill)
2. You do "fillColor=tom.color()" with gets you current color. Instead use "tom.fillcolor(fillColor)"
3. Unnecessary copying of variables radius->r and fillColor->c
4. This is python. Use for whenever possible. Instead of counting using z use:

   for _ in range(300):

My final code:

```
import turtle

def drawCircle(radius, fillColor):
    x = 360/300  # This gives the angle
    win = turtle.Screen()
    tom = turtle.Turtle()

    tom.fillcolor(fillColor)
    tom.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(300):
        tom.forward(radius)
        tom.right(x)
        tom.forward(radius)

    tom.end_fill()
    win.exitonclick()

drawCircle(1, "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have the circle-drawing down

Before addressing your fill issue, I'd argue that your premise isn't true, you *don't* have circle-drawing down.  As @Mysak0CZ shows, your circle of radius 1 is huge -- 1 what?  You're drawing a circle but have no real control over its size.

As a professional turtle wrangler, I'd go about the problem as follows. Not only your angle needs to be divided by the number of segments you plan to draw, but you need to compute a circumference based on the requested radius and chop that up as well.  I do so below and include a call to turtle's own `.circle()` method to show that we're in the right ballpark.  And I fix your minor fill issue:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen  # force object-oriented turtles

SEGMENTS = 60  # how many lines make up the circle

def drawCircle(radius, fillColor):

    distance = math.pi * radius * 2 / SEGMENTS  # circumference / SEGMENTS
    angle = 360 / SEGMENTS

    turtle.fillcolor(fillColor)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(SEGMENTS):
        turtle.forward(distance)
        turtle.left(angle)  # left for .circle() compatibility

    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

drawCircle(100, 'red')
turtle.circle(100)  # for comparison

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for a pink circle if you are going through the same Python learning resource. I think the original code was missing an argument.

```
import turtle

def drawPolygon(t, sideLength, numSides):
    t.goto(0, 0)
    turnAngle = 360 / numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.right(turnAngle)

def drawCircle(anyTurtle, radius):
    circumference = 2 * 3.1415 * radius
    sideLength = circumference / 360
    drawPolygon(anyTurtle, sideLength, 360)

def drawFilledCircle(anyTurtle, radius, color):
    anyTurtle.fillcolor(color)
    anyTurtle.begin_fill()
    drawCircle(anyTurtle, radius)
    anyTurtle.end_fill()
    anyTurtle.hideturtle()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wheel = turtle.Turtle()


drawFilledCircle(wheel, 80, "pink")

wn.exitonclick()
```